# Why can't I send the value wit the onchange?

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunction(ID) {
    var fileSelector = $('<input onchange="javascript:testFunction(' + ID + ',' + this.value  +')" type="file" />');
    fileSelector.click();
}
```

my call to the testFunction is with the correct ID, but "Undefined" for this.value

All I want is to pass the value that the input now has WITH the onchange event. Why is it not possible?

Comment: Side note, for any `on____` inline attribute you don't need to specify the `javascript:` prefix (it is the implied default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `this` keyword inside the `myFunction` function is the `window` object. You don't want that.

In fact, you want to use the `this.value` inside the HTML, so you don't need to interpolate strings.

```
function myFunction(ID) {
    var fileSelector = $('<input onchange="javascript:testFunction(' + ID + ', this.value)" type="file" />');
    fileSelector.click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what are you trying achieve is simply to remove the codes from the this.value. I did write the correct code below for your requirements:

```
var fileSelector = 
     $('<input onchange="javascript:testFunction(' + ID + ', this.value)" type="file" />');
```